# Elastic search or Trie for search/autocomplete?

Tags: algorithm, elasticsearch, autocomplete, trie

**My understanding how autocomplete/search for text/item works at high level in any scalable product like Amazon eCommerce/Google at high level was :-**

Elastic Search(ES) based approach

1. Documents are stored in DB . Once persisted given to Elastic search, It creates the index and store the index/document(based on tokenizer) in memory or disk based 
   configuration.
2. Once user types say 3 characters, it search all index under ES(Can be configured to index even ngram) , Rank them based on weightage and return to user

But after reading couple of resources on google like [Trie based search](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=us0qySiUsGU&feature=youtu.be)

Looks some of the scalable product also uses `Trie` data stucture to do the prefix based search.

My question Is Can trie based approach  be good alternative to ES or ES internally uses `Trie` or am i missing completely here ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ES autocompletion can be achieved in two ways:

1. using [`prefix` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)
2. either using [(edge-)ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html#_index_time_search_as_you_type)
3. or using the [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)

The first option is the poor man's completion feature. I'm mentioning it because it can be useful in certain situation but you should avoid it if you have a substantial amount of documents.

The second option uses the conventional ES indexing features, i.e. it will tokenize the text, all (edge-)ngrams will be indexed and then you can search for any prefix/infix/suffix that have been indexed.

The third option uses a different approach and is optimized for speed. Basically, when indexing a field of type `completion`, ES will create a ["finite state transducer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_transducer) and store it in memory for ultra fast access.

A finite state transducer is close to a trie in terms of implementation. You can check this [excellent article](https://blog.burntsushi.net/transducers) which shows how [trie](https://blog.burntsushi.net/transducers/#trie-construction) compares to [finite state transducer](https://blog.burntsushi.net/transducers/#fst-construction)

**UPDATE (June 25th, 2019):**

ES 7.2 introduced a new data type called `search_as_you_type` that allows this kind of behavior natively. Read more at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/search-as-you-type.html

Comment: Updated answer for ES 7.2