# Prefix search with frequency count

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

At the moment when I index a text, I store the frequency count of each word in a database. This works just fine since all searches are based on whole words and all possible searches are known. 
But now I want to add the option of a prefix search (search of a part of a word). I can get the results/hits from a prefix search with elasticsearch by using this:

```
GET /my_index/address/_search
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "main_text": "word_part"
        }
    }
}
```

see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/prefix-query.html

This is my current mapping:

```
{
    "my-index":{
        "mappings":{
            "doc":{
                "properties":{
                    "keycounter":{
                        "properties":{
                            "counter": {"type":"integer"},
                            "keyword":{"type":"keyword"}
                         }
                    },
                    "main_text":{
                        "type":"text", 
                        "fielddata":true
                    },
                    "main_text_keycounter":{
                        "properties":{
                            "counter":{
                                "type":"long"
                            },
                            "keyword":{
                                "type":"text", 
                                "fields":{
                                    "keyword":{
                                        "type":"keyword",
                                        "ignore_above":256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "time_written":{
                        "type":"date"
                    },
                    "translated_text":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fielddata":true
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don´t want to count the frequency for each result I get since it will cost O(N) for each text. Is there some smart way of storing/getting frequency count from this type of a search using elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [doc-termvectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) feature of elasticsearch to get the term statistics and count of the terms. Like that you can store your document using the mapping and get the statistics of the prefix term when you query it. Of course this approach provides you with term statistics per result document so you'd have to aggregate it for all of your results.

Here is an example for a mapping, indexed document and a `doc-termvectors` query. You can also use a [edge-ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer to get statistics for prefix-terms.

**Mapping**:

```
PUT /my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "main_text": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true,
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
          "store": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index document**:

```
POST /my-index/doc/1
{
  "main_text": "foo bar foo"
}
```

**Get termvectors**:

```
POST /my-index/doc/1/_termvectors
```

**Results**:

```
...
"terms": {
    ...
    "foo": {
      "term_freq": 2,
      "tokens": [
        {
          "position": 0,
          "start_offset": 0,
          "end_offset": 3
        },
        {
          "position": 2,
          "start_offset": 8,
          "end_offset": 11
        }
      ]
    }
    ...
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to get the `termvectors` for mutiple documents you can use the [_mtermvectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-termvectors.html) endpoint. It will provide you with the statistics for multiple documents. It will, however, not count term frequencies over all documents which is as I understand your question what you want. As a solution, you might store the results of `termvectors` in your elastic (either same index, or a separate) and then use an aggregation to count the overall term counts.

```
POST /my-index/doc/_mtermvectors
{
  "ids": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "fields": [
      "main_text"
    ],
    "term_statistics": true
  }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Then I think that the solution is to call `termvectors` for all documents and store the results, i.e. all the term and subterm frequencies in another index. By aggregating the results based on your search queries, wou'd get the results that you wish.

Comment: I am able to get the sum of frequency for all docs by using the last example from  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html   But how would I get the doc frequency for multiple docs in one query?

Comment: I've added some ideas on this in a edit: you can use _mtermvectors and store the results in your elastic. Afterwars you could use an aggregation to count overall frequencies

Comment: Thank you, I don’t see how to filter terms by search text though, this gives all the term vectors for all texts

Comment: Can you tell me more about your motivation? What do you need this information for?

Comment: It is for users to investigate word frequency over time, e.g. to see how the word car went from not existing over to a frequently used word in English. It is the original query in my question. It seems like the filter for term vectors is not allowing a search filter based on text, but this must be possible some how

Comment: Would it be enough for you to do a static analysis for a fixed set of terms?

Comment: It is necessary to filter based on both words and parts of words.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51085473), suggesting use of finite state transducer to speed up prefix searches for [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html). Looks pretty neat and claimed to be equivalent to trie usage