# What is the fundamental difference between ElasticSearch and a cache?

Tags: elasticsearch, caching, redis

Theoretically speaking, can't you just cache search results from a SQL query made to the database making it similar to ElastiSearch? I understand you would run into invalidation issues, but what are the fundamental differences between ElastiSearch and a cache like Redis?

Comment: Do you think that ES is being used for caching? Are you trying to understand ES against Redisearch?

Comment: @Gibbs That may be where my misunderstanding is. It seems like it's just way to achieve speed with search which is why I compared it that way.

Comment: This thread might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386108/caching-vs-indexing/34389625#34389625

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch is primarily a Search engine optimized to [store and retrieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) structured or semi-structured data. It takes care of processing structured/semi-structured data, indexes and provides a nice DSL to query data. Oh, and it happens to be super fast :)

A distributed cache like Memcached and Redis ( BTW Redis is not just cache, but a data structure store) primarily stores Key-Value pairs for faster lookup. Think of your local hash table distributed across a bunch of machines.

Two different use cases. If it's just for the cache - Elasticsearch may not be the right choice.

Comment: Follow up question what's the difference between Cache and Data Structure Store.